# FIND MAX IN A RESULT SET GROUP BY ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

I have one SQL table with following structure.

```
TravelStatgeID  TravelId    EventDateTime   Action  FromStageID ToStageID   UserID  Comments
720             1280        38:20.7         Approved    0       1           2030    NULL
721             1280        40:03.2         Approved    1       2           1913    NULL
722             1280        41:24.2         Approved    2       3           2064    NULL
723             1280        45:58.5         Approved    3       4           2229    NULL
```

This table has hundreds of records.I want to find the records which are having max of tostageid=3. I have written a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    ABC.TravelId,
    MAX(ABC.ToStageID)'STAGE'
FROM(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TravelId ORDER BY TravelId)'RN',
        * 
    FROM tbl_HR_TravelStageEvent 
)ABC
GROUP BY ABC.TravelId
HAVING MAX(ABC.ToStageID)=3
```

I don't know whether is this right way or not.Can you please give me what are the ways to find the output.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT USE ALL CAPS IN YOUR TITLES - IT MAKES IT LOOK LIKE YOU ARE SHOUTING AT US.

Comment: sorry will take care of it from next time..

Comment: Or, you could click [edit] and fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `PARTITION`? I can't see you using results of `ROW_NUMBER()` anywhere.

Try following:

```
SELECT 
    ABC.TravelId,
    MAX(ABC.ToStageID) 'STAGE'
FROM
    tbl_HR_TravelStageEvent ABC
GROUP BY
    ABC.TravelId
HAVING
    MAX(ABC.ToStageID) = 3
```

Comment: @sidD I'm glad I could help you! Looking at your profile and previously asked question you should probably look at following question: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That's how SO works and how you should mark the answer that solved your problem (not necessary mine :)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If you just want to find TravelID then use below query:

```
SELECT A.TravelId, MAX(A.ToStageID) ToStageID
FROM tbl_HR_TravelStageEvent A 
GROUP BY A.TravelId HAVING MAX(A.ToStageID) = 3
```

And if you want to find all columns of table then use below query:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM tbl_HR_TravelStageEvent A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.TravelId, MAX(A.ToStageID) ToStageID
            FROM tbl_HR_TravelStageEvent A 
            GROUP BY A.TravelId HAVING MAX(A.ToStageID) = 3
           ) B ON A.TravelId = B.TravelId AND A.ToStageID = B.ToStageID
```